Jolt Transform to empty field
I have the following example of JSON and there many other fields apart from these 3
[
  {
    "field1": "xyz",
    "field2": "mno",
    "res1": "pqrs"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1"
    
  }..other entries
]

I would like to empty the contents of field res1.
I tried this
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "res": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

but it does not work. Please help in this case.
I use this site to test my Jolt Spec

what is your input JSONArray or String? Please share the demo code from an online compiler like ....https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/ @DotNetDev19

I am using this website to do testing - https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Hi this spec will help you do it :
If you want to empty res1 field as "res1": "".
try this spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "res1": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

If you want to remove res1 field as entirely.
try this spec:
   [
      {
        "operation": "remove",
        "spec": {
          "*": {
            "res1": ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]


Can you help here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79226736/jolt-spec-to-filter-multiple-value-in-json-field

Hi Sure let me check.

Please advise here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79229923/generic-way-to-un-flatten-nested-json-using-jolt

For this question ,I emptied res1.But , Can you also please tell how can I empty on a condition. For example- if field1 is /folder/something/something then empty res1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79230638/conditional-check-to-clear-empty-field-using-jolt

Not able to answer I think question is on review.

Can you please tell here?

Added here @DotNetDev19

Hi if you want to add a condition for res1 based on field1 field try this spec:
This means if field1 is either "/folder1/subfolder/name" or "/folder2/subfolder/name" or "/folder3/subfolder/name" then res1 value stay as it is else it will be removed.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "field1": {
          "/folder1/subfolder/name|/folder2/subfolder/name|/folder3/subfolder/name": {
            "@(2,field1)": "[#4].field1",
            "@(2,field2)": "[#4].field2",
            "@(2,res1)": "[#4].res1"
          },
          "*": {
            "@(2,field1)": "[#4].field1",
            "@(2,field2)": "[#4].field2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

