Jolt Spec to filter multiple value in json field
I have the following json and would like to filter few object only -
  {
    "field1": "xyz",
    "field2": "mno",
    "res1": "pqrs",
    "folder": "/folder-parent/raw/new"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1",
    "folder": "/folder-parent/raw/old"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1",
    "folder": "/folder-parent/changed-per-record"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1",
    "folder": "/folder-parent/something-else"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1",
    "folder": "/folder-parent/something/other-thing"
  }
]


I need filtered objects with /folder-parent/raw/new /folder-parent/raw/old /folder-parent/change-per-record
I tried this but does not work [ { "operation": "shift", "spec": { "*": { "folder": { "*": { "filter": "@(2, folder)=== '/folder-parent/raw/new' && @(2, folder)=== '/folder-parent/raw/old' && @(2, folder)=== '/folder-parent/change-per-record'", "": "@" } } } } } ]
Please help in this case

Hi hope this helps you resolve your query.
Explanation :
folder : the code from folder act as an if condition if folder is
/folder-parent/raw/new Or /folder-parent/raw/old Or
/folder-parent/changed-per-record "@2" represent to pick values as its from 2 level above it and keep it an array.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "folder": {
          "/folder-parent/raw/new|/folder-parent/raw/old|/folder-parent/changed-per-record": {
            "@2": "[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thanks works , is it possible to use regex like field containing this string folder-parent?

Yes put a start "*" where ever you want to use regex.
Like in previous spec you can replace the full folder like this.
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"*": {
"folder": {
"/folder-parent/r*|/folder-parent/c*": {
"@2": "[]"
}
}
}
}
}
]
Can you please upvote and accept the answer.

accepted and upvoted! tq!
