How to flatten nested JSON with Jolt?
Hi I have following json and would like to unnest filed.So, I have an old order and new order for products. There could be more field to the json but level of nesting remains the same. Is it possible to do it via Jolt ?
I can have fields like new_something and old_something in output
{
  "data": {
    "new": {
      "orders": {
        "type": "atype",
        "currency": "usd",
        "name": null,
        "code": null,
        "shipped": null,
        "identifier": "some uuid",
        "source": "webshop",
        "productinfo": [
          {
            "pType": "fan",
            "ts": "2024-11-15T13:33:16.047Z",
            "status": null,
            "seller": {
              "identifier": "uuid",
              "internacodes": [
                {
                  "type": "US",
                  "value": "1111"
                },
                {
                  "type": "UUID",
                  "value": "some uuid"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "pType": "fan",
            "ts": "2024-11-25T13:33:16.047Z",
            "status": null,
            "seller": {
              "identifier": "uuid",
              "internacodes": [
                {
                  "type": "US",
                  "value": "1111"
                },
                {
                  "type": "UUID",
                  "value": "some uuid"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "unique_num": [
          {
            "type": "UUID",
            "value": "some uuid",
            "ts": "2024-11-13T25:15:47.919Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "product id",
            "value": "23456",
            "ts": "2024-11-22T15:15:46.912Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "old": {
      "orders": {
        "type": "atype",
        "currency": "usd",
        "name": null,
        "code": null,
        "shippedOffice": null,
        "identifier": "some uuid",
        "source": "webshop",
        "productinfo": [
          {
            "pType": "fan",
            "ts": "2024-11-15T13:33:16.047Z",
            "status": null,
            "seller": {
              "identifier": "uuid",
              "internacodes": [
                {
                  "type": "US",
                  "value": "1111"
                },
                {
                  "type": "UUID",
                  "value": "some uuid"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "unique_num": [
          {
            "type": "UUID",
            "value": "some uuid",
            "ts": "2024-11-13T25:15:47.919Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "product id",
            "value": "23456",
            "ts": "2024-11-22T15:15:46.912Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Please share advice and inputs . I tried via hardcoded operations in Jolt but field non nested field may be added .Nested one remains the same.
I need output like this -
{

   
    "data.new.orders.type": "atype",
    "data.new.orders.currency": "usd"
    .....
    "data.new.orders.productinfo.seller.identifier": "seller_identifier"
}


The question is a bit unclear. Do you want to "un-flatten" or "un-nest" (i.e. flatten) the JSON? Can you provide the expected result for the example?

Sorry for confusion, it  is to flatten the json.updated!

Which json.updated?  Please provide the desired output (for give data), to make your question clear!

I mean the whole json. and updated was for updating the question. OK I will try to add output.

I have added an example output. But please feel free to suggest if there is a better representation.

Hi this spec can help you achieve it.
Giving you small piece with 2 fields:
Basically I am skipping "." operator with "\\." escape character "\\".
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "new": {
          "orders": {
            "type": "&3\\.&2\\.&1\\.&",
            "currency": "&3\\.&2\\.&1\\.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

For productinfo since it is array it will populate as with parent key as 0,1.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "new": {
          "orders": {
            "type": "&3\\.&2\\.&1\\.&",
            "currency": "&3\\.&2\\.&1\\.&",
            "productinfo": {
              "*": {
                "pType": "&3\\.&2\\.&1\\.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Example output:
{
  "data.new.orders.type" : "atype",
  "data.new.orders.currency" : "usd",
  "orders.productinfo.0.pType" : "fan",
  "orders.productinfo.1.pType" : "fan"
}

(with help from: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception )

Can you add the field productinfo.pType (Just to make your example more complete....)?

Updated the code.

Thanks , I can start with this approach.
