Conditional check to clear/empty field using Jolt on multiple types of field values
I have the below JSON
[
  {
    "field1": "xyz",
    "field2": "mno",
    "res1": "pqrs"
  },
  {
    "field1": "xyz1",
    "field2": "mno1",
    "res1": "pqrs1"
    
  }..other entries
]


And the below jolt spec works fine to empty the field but I need to check if the value of field1 is /folder1/subfolder/name or /folder2/subfolder/name or /folder3/subfolder/name before emptying the res1
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "res": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Need help in updating the above for conditional check in Jolt Spec
Edited --I need to like this (this does not work)
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "if": "field1 == '/abc/bvcd' || field1 == '/xyz/prq/'",
        "then": {
          "res1": ""
        },
        "else": {}
      }
    }
  }
]


ok thanks I will check and update accordingly.

I think mine is different,I would like to empty the field and also multiple conditions are there.

This removes the other entries from the json but I don't want.  So, the ask here is to match a field and then empty  content of another field without removing other json object. I will try to update question with pseudo code.

@BarbarosÖzhan Edited please review

You can use the following spec :
[
  { //separate the objects by indexes and "field1" values
    //considering the case of "field1" values to be identical 
    //for different objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.@1,field1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {//empty "res1" attributes only as long as the matching occurs
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "/folder1/subfolder/name?|/folder2/subfolder/name?|/folder3/subfolder/name?": {
          "res1": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the outer keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]

where ? operator leads to conditional matching.
If any of those object keys exists, then "res1":"" match occurs for that individual one.
the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


Thank you for understanding. This works for me. I have one question what is the purpose question mark(?|) in filter?
